# NT Service BadImageFormat, but works under forms app

Tags: service, x86, badimageformatexception

We have a legacy forms application that runs a bunch of 32 bit C++ code along with managed code most of which is built x86 ( but not all.)  The forms application works fine.  We are porting the functionality/code into a windows service.  The service is throwing a bad image format exception when it attempts to execute a particular code path.

We don't have access to all the managed code builds.

Any suggestions on how to attack this problem.

Thanks in advance
bille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

There were two problems with the service side.  The actual service executable was built AnyCPU .  Also, when building services I always put the main code in a dll to allow console/form app to test drive it.  The dll was also built AnyCPU.  The form app that is working was built x86.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' (using the green checkmark) so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~